# Eclipse Maven Terminal

Tags: eclipse, maven, terminal

I have changed my javaproject via Project-> Configure-> Convert to Maven Project.
I've tried several things to include 2 jar files, which are selfprogrammed, but without any success.
Now i want to install them with the terminal in eclipse but I get the error
`The command "mvn" is either misspelled or could not be found`.
Can someone explain to me how I can setup my terminal for executing mvn commands.

Comment: Are you sure you have Maven installed on your system? Eclipse is shipped with an embedded Maven, so you can run Maven builds (via _Run > Run Configurations..._) without having Maven installed on your system.

Comment: I have installed it in the past but didnt include it in the project yet. How can I include it in a project like this?

Comment: To install Maven on your system, see http://maven.apache.org/install.html To run a Maven run configuration instead of in the terminal doing `mvn ...`, tell the `...`.